# How can I display a javascript variable multiple times in html?

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I am programming a text game that generates many variables randomly, like the character's name and the name of their ship, from arrays. Once the functions to generate those names is run, I use something like this in the body of the html:

```
<pre> The sea welcomes you back. It is finally time to achieve your destiny. Become who you were born to be.

You are <ins class="cap"></ins>, Captain of <ins id="ship"></ins>, <a id="story"></a>, and there is nothing standing between you, and fame, and fortune.

Your fearsome crew has been assembled. <ins id="crew1"></ins> is your first mate, <ins id="crew2"></ins> and <ins id="crew3"></ins> man the deck, and <ins id="crew4"></ins> is up in the crow's nest.  They are a raggedy bunch but they'll see you through if the gold is right. 

<a id="crew1"></a> glances back at the helm, ready to draw the anchor and set sail. You give the command and <ins id="ship"></ins> sets off into a bright, cloudless morning...</pre>
```

where there are these functions in the javascript to fill those in:

```
var captainName = function () {
    var e = firstName[Math.floor(Math.random() * firstName.length)] + " " + lastName[Math.floor(Math.random() * lastName.length)];
    document.getElementById("cap").innerHTML = e;
    e = captainName;
};

var ship = function () {
    var e = shipName[Math.floor(Math.random() * shipName.length)];
    document.getElementById("ship").innerHTML = e;
    e = shipName;
};

captainName();
ship();
```

and it will display like this:

You are Django de Bois, Captain of The Black Beauty.

However, when I want to display the name of the character again, and I use another  tag in the html, it remains empty. I think it doesn't want the repeated tag to have the same id but I can't be sure. I am very new to javascript and programming in general and learning on my own, so feel free to point out something that may seen obvious.

Comment: If you are going to repeat elements, you should use classes instead of ids. Ids are for single instances. Also, please post some HTML to show us better what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the same ID twice. Only the first one is taken into account in JS because it's not expecting extras, and in HTML it's against the standards and is actually invalid HTML.

You need to either use different IDs for each element, and pass the ID you want as an argument to the function:

```
var captainName = function (id) {
    var e = firstName[Math.floor(Math.random() * firstName.length)] + " " + lastName[Math.floor(Math.random() * lastName.length)];
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = e;
    e = captainName; // <-- also, what is this for? 
};
```

Or use classes instead, and target them all at once:

```
var captainName = function () {
    var e = firstName[Math.floor(Math.random() * firstName.length)] + " " + lastName[Math.floor(Math.random() * lastName.length)];
    // you can use forEach to iterate through them
    document.getElementsByClassName("cap").forEach(function(el)
        el.innerHTML = e;
    });
    e = captainName;
};
```